# Save data from editable division

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I am having  editable div.
I need to store the contents of that division into a mysql table.

Which all events are available for a division?

Is there any `onBlur` event for divisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the list of events for a `div` element in IE on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535240(VS.85).aspx

The `onblur` event is there, and many others will work in other browsers too.  The Mozilla Developer Center doesn't mention whether or not DIV elements support `onfocus` and `onblur` in Firefox, but those specific events *should* fire if the element is content editable or the tabindex attribute set to `0`.